# How can I deploy a Xbox 360 game onto a disc?

Tags: xna-4.0, xbox360, deployment

I'm making some games for Windows now since about 3 years using the Microsoft XNA Framework and C#. Now I finally came to buy myself a Xbox 360 and now I want to deploy some games I converted to Xbox 360 onto a CD to give it away to my friends. What tools would I need and how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XNA only supports distribution of your final game via the Xbox Live service. You cannot print discs that will run on a retail console.

You will require an [XNA Creator's Club](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/XNA-Creators-Club/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802584e07d1) membership, which is a subscription-based membership with an annual fee, in order to publish your game to the platform. Your friends will then be able to log on to Xbox Live and get it.

Your only other real option is to mod your console to support homebrew development. This will allow you to run unsigned executables (although usually not via discs, distribution via USB or similar is more common). It will likely require you to rewrite your games, since the XNA framework is supported by the homebrew development toolchain. Also, all of your friends will need to have modified consoles as well. Doing this will void your warranty and in the past has caused users to get banned from Xbox Live. Not all versions of the console are moddable, as well. I don't recommend this route, but there is plenty of information and guides out there on the internet on the process (which would not be appropriate to collect here).

Comment: I think the fee is only 20$ these days.  It is definitely that price for the Windows Phone, and the membership was unified at one point.

Comment: That makes sense. I can't actually find the order form at the moment either.

Comment: I went through the process (LIVE password reset, xboxlive sign, and all) and it turns out it still costs 99$.  At least the page on which I landed claims so.  I might try plunking down for the cheap phone dev membership in an effort to sneakily save 80$.

Comment: More important comment: if your friends also have Creator's Club memberships, you can simultaneously deploy your game from VS and test its network multiplayer, without formal publishing.  Clearly this is more involved than distributing CDs (and costs even more than a single membership), but it is possible.